# What are the differences between difficulties in Megaman 2 for the iOS?

Tags: ios, mega-man-2

In Megaman 2 for iOS, there are two difficulty levels: classic and new. What are the differences between these two modes.  I think Classic seems to have less forgivable controls, although I can't confirm this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic mode is the original NES game and has the original controls as they were on the NES.

New mode is a modified version of the game with "more forgiving" controls, as stated in the app description. In this mode, the bosses and enemies are not as strong and the player takes less damage. There is an auto-fire option, as well as the ability to exit a level in the pause menu, return to the title screen, and select another one.

Answer (score 1):

If it's NES Mega Man 2, bosses take half damage in the harder mode, along with some more subtle changes.

But I assume that it's not a difficulty level, rather a "pick your game" where Classic is the NES game and "New " is something different.

Comment: I recall something saying that it was a new difficulty level. There is a link to the game above and there is a free demo if you would like to do some research.